# Add to cart resulting in 404 error - PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on a Prestashop 1.7 shop and I have an issue. When I clicked on the "Add to cart" button, I'm getting an Error 404 (Not Found) in the JS Console.

This shop is installed on a Apache server:

- I have tried to reload the `.htaccess`, I checked if `AllowOverride all` is set up in the virtual host config.
- I have tried to clear cache and force re-compile the theme in the Back Office.
- I have tried to change the theme of the website.
- I have tried to enable mod rewrite.

However, when I disable friendly URLs, the "Add to card" button works perfectly !

How I can solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you getting this issue only with the Add to cart button? What about other rewrited URLs such as product pages or category pages?

Comment: Only with the Add to cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen with you through via chat, we:

1. Regenerated your .htaccess file
2. Made sure SSL was turned on sitewide
3. Disabled some 3rd party modules that were causing redirects
4. Upgraded to PrestaShop v1.7.5.2

And your issue was resolved!